# "You cannot specify a different service agreement in FI" returned from Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments, ruby-on-rails-6

I am triying to create stripe connected account in testing mode referencing

```
service_agreement: 'recipient'
```

here with the full code I wrote:

```
account = Stripe::Account.create(
        type: 'custom',
        business_type: 'company',
        email: account_params[:email],
        external_account: "btok_us_verified",
        capabilities: {
          transfers: {requested: true}
        },
        company: {
          name: "Test Company name 6", 
          tax_id: "000000000", 
        },
        tos_acceptance: {
          service_agreement: 'recipient',
          date: Time.now.to_i,
          ip: request.remote_ip,
        }
      )
```

After I made the call stripe returned this error.

```
You cannot specify a different service agreement in FI.
```

But stripe [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/required-verification-information#FI-company-transfers-recipient) says recipient service agreement is available.

Can anyone help me to figure out this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible, or at least it worked when I tested using my test US-based platform. You may need to explicitly specify the account `country=FI`:

```
account = Stripe::Account.create(
        type: 'custom',
        **country: 'FI',**
        business_type: 'company',
        email: account_params[:email],
        external_account: "btok_us_verified",
        capabilities: {
          transfers: {requested: true}
        },
        company: {
          name: "Test Company name 6", 
          tax_id: "000000000", 
        },
        tos_acceptance: {
          service_agreement: 'recipient',
          date: Time.now.to_i,
          ip: request.remote_ip,
        }
      )
```

If this does not resolve it for you I can create a test FI platform to try myself.

Comment: Yeah, I tried this by explicitly specifying the country. But it also gave the same error message. I also assume the reason could be that it's not a us-based platform. But couldn't find any stripe document or article to prove this.